# Fibration with total space $SU(3)$, base $S^5$ and fiber $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, fibration, tangent-bundle

I would like to find a fibration with total space $SU(3)$, base $S^5$ and fiber $S^3$.

Any idea?

Comment: See the top answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69352/topology-of-su3?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The action of $SU(3)$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$ preserves the unit sphere $S^5$, and the stabilizer of a point is $SU(2) = S^3$.